# Bootstrap Responsive Menu won't Respond

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm having a bad time with this Bootstrap menu I made, and I can't figure it out why it won't collapse, animate.
Everything works great and all, but the button doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/lib/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</header>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container">
<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Dropdown</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Tell me More</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Login</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Sign up</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Some help, please?

Comment: I'm also using Firefox.

Comment: Have you linked bootstrap.js to the code you tested? If you did, did you put it **after** jQuery(which is compulsory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container">
<div class="container">
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Dropdown</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Tell me More</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Login</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Sign up</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is a working example. With the **data-target=".navbar-collapse"** @Peszo said it does not work. The most usefull fact would be to resize the window when using the code snippet.

Comment if you encounter any more issues. +1 if it helps.

**EDIT** As on demand, I have further styled the navbar.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container">
<div class="container">
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tell me More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am glad. That is a common error developers should check. If it worked and you are pleased with the answer, could you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

may be you are using old version jquery library file. Use latest version file.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0s266y3s/)

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..
you use `<a>` tag after `<li>` tag...

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        **<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tell me More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Login</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Sign up</a></li>**
    </ul>
</div>
```